# I need to create a dialog box in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need a some help... I am needing to create a script so if a cell is greater than 13 it pops up a warning dialog box asking do they want to continue; is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

`function onEdit()` to let Apps Script run a function automatically
   if a certain event occurs

Example from Google Developers (please adjust to your needs):

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

---

`function openDialog()` to open a dialog box

Example:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('nameofyourhtmlcode')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(html);
}
```

---

nameyourhtmlcode => you can create a html with informations/data you want to display